# Trying to set up urls.py to direct to index.html

Tags: python, django

As the question implies, I am trying to set up my urls.py file to point towards my index.html file.

Here is the structure of my project:

```
-->mysiteX
---->.idea
---->mysite
------->migrations
       __init__
       admin.py
       apps.py
       models.py
       test.py
       views.py
---->mysiteX
-------->templates
            index
       ---->css
       ---->fonts
       ---->js
       ---->vendors
       __init__
       settings
       urls
       wsgi
----->venv
db.sqlite3
manage
```

This is what my urls.py file looks like

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

my views.py file

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
def index_file(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

settings.py:

```
import os, sys
abspath = lambda *p: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(*p))

PROJECT_ROOT =  abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_ROOT)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    abspath(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
)
```

When I run manage.py I get this page
[image: landing page]

Update after making changes  to my urls.py file to this extent:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from gradientboost import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^/$',views.index_file,name='index')
]
```

This is what I am getting
[image: update]

Second Update
changed my settings.py file according to an answer given

```
import os, sys

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysiteX/templates')
...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

However still getting this error
[image: second update]

Comment: what do you see in this address ?:  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index`

Comment: @shotgunner I added a screenshot at the end of my question

Comment: your screenshot is show `127.0.0.1:8000` not `127.0.0.1:8000/index`

Comment: @shotgunner returns the django administration login page

Comment: @Emm Please Check My Comment And Try Hopefully This Time It Will Work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Need To Change Your `Urls.py`

Because You Are Changing Admin Url Admin Url Is For Admin Login And For Website Control!

and if you add `index/` than you need to type in your brower like that `domainname.com/index`

So if you Want Your `index.html` show on website home page try my code:

Try This If You browsing this link 127.0.0.1:8000

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index_file, name='YOUR NAME')
]
```

And if you trying this link 127.0.0.1:8000/index Try This:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^index/$', views.index_file, name='YOUR NAME')
]
```

Also Add This In Your Settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'mysiteX/templates')
```

And Also Add This In your Settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: @Emm What You Are Typing In Your Browser?

Comment: Can You Share Link?

Comment: @Emm Please Write This: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ And Let Me Know Is it Work?

Comment: @Emm Is That Work?

Comment: @Emm Can You Please Share Screenshot?

Comment: added that to my question

Comment: @Emm Sorry I Forget To Remove `url(r'^/$', views.index_file, name='YOUR NAME')` / There Please replace This Line With This: `url(r'^$', views.index_file, name='YOUR NAME')` an try with this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: seem to be getting this message now -> 'templatedoesnotexist at/ index.html'

Comment: @Emm Answer Updated Please Check

Comment: still getting the same error will update question with updated code based on your answer

Comment: @Emm I Tried My Best I Think I Can't Fix Your issue because I Think you are using Old Version Django i can give you one last thing that can you please move your templates folder on first mysiteX and delete my settings code and try make sure you don't delete my urls code thanks i'm sorry if this also don't work but i tried my best to fix this issue thanks but please try that

Comment: @Emm Try To Remove my setting code and try to move your templates folder to first mysiteX  and try hopefully it will work

Comment: @Emm Template Dose Not Exist Django Can't Find Template folder please try my upper comment formula i pretty sure that can help you

Answer (score 0):

create a html template index.html and your url should be redirected the view.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^index/', your_view, name = 'index'),
]
```

Comment: bit of a dumb question, but i'm guessing 'your view' = the page I would like to direct to? i.e 'index.html'?

Comment: yes, it is your index file view, import the view on to of url also.

Answer (score 0):

You don't reference templates from your `urls.py`. That is for matching routes up to view functions, and it is the view's job to tell Django to render a template, if appropriate. You already have a simple view that renders `index.html`, you just need to reference it in your urlconf.

If you want your `index.html` rendered at the root of your site, then you need to add this line to your `urls.py` (EDIT: fixed the route):

```
url(r'^$', index_file)
```

You will also need `from mysite.views import index_file` at the top of your urlconf.

Comment: can you give more detail about the error message please? It's likely an issue with your template setting or location.

Comment: I added a screenshot with the error message to my question

Comment: Thanks, I now realise I had the wrong regex for the domain root (it's been a while since I used Django and I misremembered). It should be just `r'^$'` - I'll edit my answer